# SVG patterns rasterised when printing to PDF

Tags: svg

I'm trying to create a SVG file what when printed to PDF maintains all of its parts in vector. This file uses a pattern as a fill to a path, or in the example bellow as the fill to the `rect` element:

```
    <svg
        width="200"
        height="200"
        viewBox="0 0 200 200"
        version="1.1"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        className="productWrapper"
      >
        <defs>
          <pattern id="pattern" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1">
            <path
              fill="#fcc"
              d="[vector path here]"
            />
          </pattern>
        </defs>
        <rect fill="url(#pattern)" stroke="black" width="200" height="200" />
      </svg>
```

The issue I'm facing is that when printed to PDF the `rect` element or any `path` at the top level of the SVG file stays vector, but all vector content inside the `pattern` is rasterized.

A very minimal example of this can be found here:

https://6j8953j8rn.codesandbox.io/

Any way to get the SVG to render in vector when printing to PDF?

Comment: How do you "print" those to PDF?

Comment: @Sirko I will be using puppeteer but I've confirmed that when doing a print to PDF using the browser print feature, the result is the same.

Comment: Did someone solve it at the end? I am running into the same issue.

Comment: @JonathanHeinen I'm afraid this is a limitation with how browsers treat SVGs so last time I've looked there was no way around it.

Answer (score 0):

One tool that kept vector info after converting from SVG (including `<pattern>`) to PDF (I used it as CLI) is https://github.com/typst/svg2pdf

Some online converters also could do it while the most of other tools I tried make content inside `<pattern>` raster.